# How to use light sensor when the device is suspended (with screen off) in Android?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I already use SensorEventListener to read light values in background. My problem is when the device is locked with the screen off it stops the light sensor readings.

Comment: What API Level do you target?

Comment: @NirDuan API Level 24